# Android multipart/x-mixed-replace - decode bitmap from inputstream returns null

Tags: android, mjpeg

I'm reading a stream but when I'm trying to decode it (converting into a bitmap) I'm getting null, no exception is thrown.

This is my code:

```
HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(URI.create(link));
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufHttpEntity.getContent());
```

The `InpuStream` which I get from `bufHttpEntity.getContent()` is not null, it has 38 KB data.
All I know about the stream server is that the header has content-type: `multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=<boundary-name>`

If I'm opening the link in a browser, it is working, I can see the image, but when I'm trying to convert it into a Bitmap I'm getting null.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the docs of `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`:

> The decoded bitmap, or null if the image data could not be decoded.

And I guess that's what causes the issue. `multipart` means the content can contain multiple files, separated by the boundary and individual headers. Even if there is only one file, it will be framed by the header, and a boundary at the start and the end. I honestly don't know what `multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=<boundary-name>` means in detail.

The `HttpEntity` does not remove the boundary, and thus the Bitmap cannot be decoded.

Try to save the content to a file, and view that in a HEX viewer. You'll then know how you have to "convert" the received data so you can decode the bitmap.